# PHP - mySQL query returns no data on first attempt

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm no guru with this so please be patient:

I have a jQuery call to a PHP page that then executes a query and returns the result when the user chooses items from a list. However there is no result the first time the list is clicked, but the correct results are returned on subsequent clicks. The jQuery code is doing as expected and sending the correct information - it is only the results that are not working properly.

jQuery Code (Note that filenames and data in CurrentClientID are correct. The alert is only for testing):

```
$.post("include/ListClientAddr.php",{ clientid:CurrentClientID },function(result){
            alert(CurrentClientID + " | " + result);
        });
```

PHP Code (database has already been successfully connected):

```
$ThisClientID=$_POST['clientid'];

$sql="SELECT Address_Type FROM Address_Table WHERE Client_ID='" . $ThisClientID . "'";

//get the result
$result=mysql_query($sql);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['Address_Type'].",";
}
```

Return results should be a comma delimited list of numbers. In the jQuery code above the alert produces the correct Client ID number and nothing the first time that the user clicks a list item, but the second time clicking the same list item will produce the expected result.

This will happen the first time ANY item in the list is clicked - if another item is clicked straight away the correct results are shown, and if the same item is clicked straight away it will also return the correct results.

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with this?

many thanks

BK

EDIT:
Further testing shows that every item in the list needs to be clicked twice in order to return the correct data.

Iv been going over and over the code but I cant see why this is happening.

Cheers

BK

Answer (score 0):

Is this a dropdown list? What's the calling function? If it's an "onchange" event, then it won't call your data function until the selected index changes in the list.

Comment: No its a live click event used on a customized unordered list - I'm using several around the page and this is the only one that fails so far.

Comment: Can you post the code for control and click event? If this is working in other places then something must be awry on this particular control or event.

Comment: I'm using:
$("#TheList li").live('click', function() {
followed by the code posted above. This is the same code that works in other places, and it works the second time the list is clicked, just not the first time.

Comment: Solution:

My own stupidity!

I was calling a $post() twice in the same function, but one after the other. $post does not work like that and the second post needed to be inside the success function of the first, not below it entirely.

I apologise for my blindness in not seeing this sooner - it *is* actually something that I already know about from previous experience but... cant see the wood for the trees and all that.

Many thanks for your efforts

BK